# Bold calligraphic typeface

Tags: fonts, bold, mathcal

I know `\mathcal{ABC...}`, but can't bold these

Answer (score 34):

You can define your own math alphabet that accesses the Computer Modern symbol font in its bold weight.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{A}$ $\mathbfcal{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: What does each of the arguments do? I get a bold font that is different from the mathcal in the particular article latex format, was wondering how to modify to make them consistent. I suspect that I should change cmsy by some other font.

Answer (score 22):

You're going to need a font that contains bold calligraphic fonts. One possibility for fonts without it is to use the [bm](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/bm.pdf) package.

```
\bm{\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}}
```

Comment: This also works for bolding greek letters in math mode, e.g. \bm{\alpha}

Answer (score 6):

In mathematical environment you may use `\boldsymbol`

here is my suggestion:

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}
\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\HH}{\bs{\mathcal{H}}}
\newcommand{\DD}{\bs{\mathcal{D}}}
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}}
\begin{document}
$\nabla\times\HH-\pd{\DD}{t}=\bs{j}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to bite the bullet and use LuaTeX with OpenType math fonts. In Context mkiv you can use

```
\setupbodyfont[xits]

\starttext
${\bf\cal abc}$
\stoptext
```

To get bold calligraphic fonts. As a bonus you get lowercase calligraphic as well. I am sure that `unicode-math` for `lualatex` has something similar.

Comment: Yep: `\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}`...`$\mathbfcal{abc}$`. Can be used in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

In `unicode-math`, `\mathbfcal` or `\symbfcal`.

In `mathalpha`, which is compatible with PDFLaTeX, `\mathbcal`. This gives you a nearly-comprehensive selection of all available 8-bit fonts, with a consistent interface, and scaling.

**Update:** Version 1.14 and higher of `mathalpha` changed the command to `\mathbfcal`.  The old name is available as an alias if you give it the `[oldbold]` package option.

Answer (score 0):

I find that `\boldsymbol` works (for both mathcal and greek letters!).

But I stumbled upon this question when it stopped working for me. Turns out the culprit was the `breqn` package; I was able to get my `\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}` to show up as a calligraphy F after *removing* `\usepackage{breqn}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}
% \usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}$

\end{document}
```