# LaTeX Calligraphic Script Bold

Tags: fonts, math-mode, bold

Does anyone know how to bold calligraphic `\mathscr` fonts in a math environment? I can get a fancy calligraphic font if I use `\mathscr`, but `\boldsymbol` does not work, nor does `\mathbf`. There is a hack which uses poor man's bold, but I was wondering if there is an alternate way to do this "cleanly". I've also seen `\bm` used for `\mathcal` font, but that's not what I'm looking for unfortunately.

I'm using calligraphic fonts with the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: [Does this  question on bold calligraphic typeface](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/bold-calligraphic-typeface) help?

Comment: I did take a look at that question, but unfortunately it doesn't help. The \mathcal fonts are easy to bold with \bm or any standard bold command. I have yet to find a solution for bold facing the \mathscr font.

Answer (score 12):

The RSFS fonts are not available in a bold version. You can however use the `\pmb` command from the `amsbsy` package, which simulates a bold weight by putting three copies of the respective character next to each other.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{ABC}$\par
$\pmb{\mathscr{ABC}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Another option is to use one of the calligraphic fonts provided by the `mathdesign` package, which resemble the RSFS fonts very closely and have bold weights.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscrbf}{OMS}{mdugm}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{ABC}$\par
$\mathscrbf{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 6):

One way is to switch to LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX) with the `unicode-math` package. This allows you to use any OpenType math font. Complete OpenType math fonts should implement all math characters from Unicode, which in particular includes bold script letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
% In TeX Live 2011 you can use 'lmmath-regular.otf' instead to get a math font that is
% matching with the default Latin Modern text font.

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{ABCabc}$

$\mathbfscr{ABCabc}$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Be aware however that these technologies are currently still in development and might contain some bugs.