# How to get a fat version of \mathscr{D}?

Tags: fonts, mtpro

I'm trying to write a curly/curvy D and it is not `\mathcal{D}` or even `\mathfrak{D}`, rather it seems that it is `\mathscr{D}` I'm looking for, but then when I do write that it is a very thin capital D. I want a fat curvy one, just as shown in the figure below. Anyone know how to get one like that?

**Edit:** with fat I mean one which is **wide** with a lot of **white space inside it.**

[image: Curly Fat D, not thin!!]

Comment: I believe this is the [math script D](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2uVYS.png) from the [MTPro2 fonts](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html). It also has a [bold variant](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6wPGm.png) if required.

Comment: Could you write that as an answer @PaulGessler?

Comment: Hahaha they want $149 for that font...

Comment: @LoveLearning That's about 'par for the course' for a commercial font: they are non-trivial thing!

Comment: Doesn't matter, it still made me lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174457/how-to-get-a-fat-version-of-mathscrd#comment403476_174457) into an answer:

The glyph in question is the math script "D" from the [MathTime Professional 2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) fonts set:

[image]

It also has a bold variant if required:

[image]

The script font is not available in the free "Lite" version of the fonts, only in the "Complete" version available for purchase. To my knowledge, a similar symbol in a free font does not exist.

If cost is more of a priority than matching the glyph style exactly, you may be interested in reviewing Christian's excellent answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124/21344) for more alternative script fonts. Check the "Calligraphic" section of the image posted in his answer.

Comment: Do you know any way to get this curly D without paying $149? I don't mean pirating, rather an alternative way to simply get this D from some other font, or is it registered?

Comment: @LoveLearning, I have updated my answer with additional information in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use LuaLaTeX:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[\mbfscrD^{(j_1)}_{m^{\phantom{\prime}}_1 m^{\prime}_1}(\mathbf{R})\mbfscrD^{(j_2)}_{m^{\phantom{\prime}}_2 m^{\prime}_2}(\mathbf{R})\]
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\[\mbfscrD^{(j_1)}_{m^{\phantom{\prime}}_1 m^{\prime}_1}(\mathbf{R})\mbfscrD^{(j_2)}_{m^{\phantom{\prime}}_2 m^{\prime}_2}(\mathbf{R})\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

All available symbols of the `unicode-math` package can be found in its documentation. These are 6 versions of a bold script latin uppercase "D":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can have real bold calligraphic fonts thanks to `Michael Sharpe`'s packages:  `dutchcal` makes available Elsevier's calligraphic font, `boondox` makes available the eponymous font in two forms. Finally `bickham` makes available Adobe's Bickham Script Pro; this one requires some small work  from the user: the font is Opentype  and has to be converted to type 1 first, with the `LCDF Type Tools` and more specifically by `cfftot1`. As the font, though freely downloadable, remains Adobe's property, so that the conversion has to be done by the user. Let me add that it also has a semi-bold version, and that you can call it either as `mathcal/\mathbcal` or as  `\mathscr/\mathbscr` if you want to keep using the default \mathcal.

Here is an example of a code that shows how to use them (I comment all \usepackage but one):

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

        \usepackage{dutchcal}
        %\usepackage{boondox-cal}
        %\usepackage{boondox-calo}
        %\usepackage{bickham}

        \begin{document}%

         \[  \mathcal{D}\quad\mathbcal{D} \]%

        \end{document}
```

Dutchcal:

[image]

Boondox:

[image]

Boondoxo:

[image]

Bickham:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To *mimic* a bold version of `\mathscr` one option is to use [amsbsy](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsbsy) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{D}$\par
$\pmb{\mathscr{D}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `\pmb` is not an actual bold as package documentation suggests:

> **\pmb**: Poor man's bold command, works by typesetting multiple copies of the
> given argument with small offsets.

[Credit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23741/22492).

Comment: Hi thanks for replying @Pouya, but these don't look like the one in  the figure :(

Comment: @LoveLearning, Is you problem with the shape of `D` or the way it has been made bold?

Comment: The shape is not the same man. Do you know how to get the shape of MTPro2(D) without paying $149 (no pirating)?

Comment: Are you open to `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`?

Comment: Ehm, I use LaTeX,