# How to type the bold script in latex?

Tags: math-mode, bold

Hello, everyone, I want to ask, how to type this formula in latex? Thank you So much!
[image: A Formula in quantum mechanics]

Comment: Why is biblatex tagged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font usually used for math script does not have a bold variant, but you can emulate something like bold by using the `\pmb` command from the `amsbsy` package, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23741/411) to a similar question.

(There are other solutions in that thread you might also consider.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\begin{document}

$\pmb{\mathscr{E}} = \mathscr{E}\negthinspace\mathbf{e}_{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image: script bold E]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem exactly and was very helpful！